# Difference between Debian CD and DVD

Tags: debian, installation, iso-image

What is the difference between Debian CD and DVD choice in ISO install package and in download menu ?
why is the DVD one 6 times bigger in size?

Comment: Refer :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117631/what-are-the-different-cds-dvds-for

Answer (score 0):

DVD contains more packages that can be installed offline.